# What snake is this, in a cave in southern Italy?

Tags: trekking, snakes

I've found this snake in a cave named *Grotta delle fate* (cave of the fairies) close to [*Forre di Lavello*](https://goo.gl/maps/PmMhEJQk5x4fReTS8) in [Cusano Mutri](http://matese.guideslow.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2015/02/BN_023_cusano_mutri.jpg).

As soon as it saw me, it seem to be not aggressive at all, but rather scared, and apparently it was just trying to find a place to hide, so I guess it is maybe not dangerous at all.

What snake you think it is the one in the photo below?

More info:

- I think it is long as much as 60-80 cm;
- I don't it'll help, but [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/4XuNjpB5WbYScrNDA) is the video which I extracted the screenshot from.

[image]

Comment: That's a very hard answer to give - you have a blurry photo that doesn't really show anything other than some stripes on the side, and may not even be true-colour, given that most snakes are brown rather than grey. It also has no indication of size - can you give us a hint as to how long and thick the snake was?

Comment: @bob1, question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching a bit on the web, I found that snake is most likely a [*Natrix natrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grass_snake) ([here](https://matese.guideslow.it/anfibi-rettili-amori-difficoltosi/) is a reference, but in italian).

Answer (score 0):

**What snake is this, in a cave in southern Italy?**

Upon close examination of the above I photo in the question, I would conclude that the snake in question is a [Vipera walser](http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Vipera&species=walser) If one looks closely one can see both the side and back marking match the photo below.

Both side and back markings are visual in the posted photo, even though somewhat blurry :

[image: Viper walser]

[Vipera walser](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_walser)

More information may be gleaned from the following articles:

- [Vipera walser GHIELMI, MENEGON, MARSDEN, LADDAGA & URSENBACHER, 2016](http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Vipera&species=walse)
- [Visper walser](https://www.herpfolio.net/vipera-walser/)

Comment: What makes you think this isn't the common European viper (_Vipera berus_)? According to most sites they are very similar in appearance; [biggest difference being number of scales on various parts of the body](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/extinction-countdown/alps-new-viper/).